# Excel how to combine 2 columns with interleaved empty cells

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns: col1, col2
Both have interleaved data and empty cells like the image here-
[image]

How do I combine col1,2 contents to get col3.

I tried using If to find empty cells and not copy content when cell was empty, but the destination column was overwritten by blank cell.

Comment: concatenate the two cells

Comment: Cell C1: `=A1&B1`. Only one will show if the other is empty

Comment: This is so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different way. Try below formulas-

```
=A2&B2
=CONCATENATE(A2,B2)
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),B2,A2)
```

[image]